Pycharm doesn't import my python libraries
I've installed python on my pc and installed many libraries like (numpy, pandas, seaborn, matplotlib...)
When i open pycharm i can't import'em, the message id (no module named numpy).
And the file of sites_packges in pycharm it's had a red color like this photo
I reinstalled pycharm and I thought it could not access the Python files installed on the device and that would help in reading the files, but it did not work

Show us the exact command you used to install the libraries.

That's probably because Python in your PyCharm project and Python with preinstalled libraries are two different Pythons.
You should go to Configuration settings -> Environment -> Python interpreter and choose the right Python or just install all libraries for currently used one.
`
For example if your Python interpreter path is D:\blablabla\venv\Scripts\python.exe you could install numpy with command D:\blablabla\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install numpy

I would like to append to this that if you want to check if they are actually installing, try running the install command again, and it will tell you where it is installed to(if it is already installed), and will tell you that it is installed. If you want to check that it is properly installed after this, you can load up IDLE on that version of python(IDLE should be installed automatically), and try to import the libraries - If they import fine on that version, then it says that have linked up your install directory not to python.
